# Lua Table in Table Showing as Nil

Tags: types, lua, null, lua-table

I'm learning to code in Lua and came across a problem with my code, this is my first time using tables and whenever I call a specific table within another table I get nil for the type and printing the table doesn't show table: xxxxx as it usually would (it just prints a blank) which I'm assuming means I have done something wrong when defining the table?

**Code:**

```
local craft = { sword = { "cobble", stick = {} } }

print(type(craft.sword[1]))
print(craft.sword[1])
print(type(craft.sword[2]))
print(craft.sword[2])
print(craft)
```

(This is a simplified version of the table, to test this error but it still occurs here)

**Output:**

```
string
cobble
nil

table: 8a3b983
```

Comment: Are you using a standard Lua interpreter? The output for the 4th `print` should be `nil`, not a blank line.

Comment: No, I am using the "Computercraft" mod for Minecraft which I am guessing uses a customised interpreter.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to add that information for future reference. When you do that we could both delete our comments to clean the thread up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`craft.sword` contains the keys `1` and `"stick"`, not `1` and `2`. What you've done is equivalent to:

```
local craft = {}
craft.sword = {}
craft.sword[1] = "cobble"
craft.sword.stick = {}
```

Note that at no point is anything stored in craft.sword[2].

More generally, if you declare a table using values but not keys, as in `{ "one", "two", "three" }`, it assigns them to numeric indexes, starting from 1. If you declare it using keys and values, as in `{ first = "one", second = "two", third = "three" }`, those values are stored *only* in the keys you specified, and nothing is stored in the numeric indexes automatically. If you mix them, as you've done here - with `{ "cobble", stick = {} }` - the values that don't have a key (`"cobble"`) are automatically assigned to the numeric indexes, and the ones that do (`stick = {}`) are assigned to the keys you specify.

The complete specification for how table declarations work is explained in [the manual under Table Constructors](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.8).

Comment: Thank you, I've simply removed the `stick =` from the code in my program and it works perfectly! It seems obvious to me now what I did wrong but I couldn't for the life of me work out what I had got wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Your table `sword` in table `craft` has a mixed index of both array-like part and hash-like part. So

```
local craft = { sword = { "cobble", stick = {} } }
```

is equivalent to

```
local craft = { sword = { 1 = "cobble", stick = {} } }
```

or (`stick` is a string index)

```
local craft = { sword = { [1] = "cobble", ["stick"] = {} } }
```

If you need to put the anonymous table in the index `2`, you can use it like this:

```
local craft = { sword = { "cobble", { stick = {} } } } 
--                                  ^            ^
```

Output of your test code on my machine:

```
string
cobble
table
table: 003CA158
table: 003CB0C8
```